# Removing leftover laminate tile adhesive

Tags: flooring

I've got an older house that had laminate tile put down in the kitchen. I've peeled up the tile using a heat gun to reveal beautiful fir flooring underneath, but there's a sticky residue left. I'm assuming this is the left over glue.

How can I remove this sticky substance without destroying the soft wood underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really hot water.  Have tons of towels and buckets handy so water does sit long.  Repeat until it comes up.

Comment: Would one of those floor steamer cleaners work too?

Comment: Sure if you get it wet enough with them.  The residue might get on the steamer so better get a commercial one.  But seriously we run into this a few times a year.  Big pasta pots and boiling water.  Never needed to rent anything.   Plastic scraper helps move things along but even the plastic can scratch floor a little.

Comment: And this doesn't leave the floor swollen and rough?

Comment: @isherwood - no.  Floors don't swell because they get water.  Floor swell because water sits on them.

Comment: Hot water works well. I had a ladybug steamer that worked almost as well just a little less water to mop up but it took longer so I went back to boiling+